# Is there a better way of disabling memory monitor hook

Tags: performance-optimization, performance

I am working on performance tuning for a Sitecore website. My current task is to disable memory monitor hook. For this, I am referring to Sitecore's tuning guide which can be found [here](https://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore7/70/cms_tuning_guide_sc70-usletter.pdf). Now, according to the section 7.3.3, in order to disable memory monitor, I need to **comment out** specific lines in **web.config**.

However, I was wondering if there is a better way to do this? I know for changing the 'Setting', we would do it by providing a patch file. I was wondering if I could do the same here without directly changing the web.config file or is that the only option for me in this particular case.

Please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a patch file to do this too. Using the `<patch:delete />` method:

```
<hook type="Sitecore.Diagnostics.MemoryMonitorHook, Sitecore.Kernel">
    <patch:delete />
</hook>
```

Add that to a config in your include folder and it will remove the memory hook config without having to directly edit the `web.config` file.

Comment: Thank you so much. I did not know that I could do that and I really did not want to change the `web.config` file directly :)

Answer (score 3):

Richard's answer is absolutely correct.

It removes the memory monitor hook completely.

If you want to disable it only, you can change the `Check Interval` attribute only with `00:00:00` value.

Just drop the patch config file to `App_config\Include` with the following content:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
    <sitecore>
        <hooks>
            <hook type="Sitecore.Diagnostics.MemoryMonitorHook, Sitecore.Kernel">
                <param  patch:instead="*[@desc='Check interval']" desc="Check interval">00:00:00</param>
            </hook>
        </hooks>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```